# Applescript IF statement with click and keystroke?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, click

I would like to make a script that press down the shift button every time i click on something and maintains it pressed until I release click.
Something like:

If click then key down shift
"when click released" key down shift

Thank you for your help I've been struggling with this one !

Comment: Which real-world problem/usage scenario are you trying to solve with this? There might be easier solutions out their than AppleScript, depending on the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to do that with AppleScript, but you could add something like this to KeyRemap4MacBook's [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<autogen>__PointingButtonToKey__ PointingButton::MIDDLE, KeyCode::SHIFT_L</autogen>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).